# MySql reserved word in select with alias table name

Tags: mysql

I've read the other MySQL reserved words questions that suggest using backticks when calling reserved words in MySQL.

Unfortunately, I've tried those and they haven't worked in my particular case where multiple tables/table aliases are being used.  My query looks like:

```
select rf.id, `s.Status` as 'Status'
from form rf 
left outer join sharerequest rr on rr.formId = rf.id
left outer join schedule s on s.sharerequestid = rr.id
```

I've tried different variations of this (backticks around just the word "status", encapsulating it in brackets (like SQLServer)) and nothing has worked.

I'm pretty sure backticks are how I'm supposed to handle this but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I couldn't see how you joined table b

Comment: I suggest the reading of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378/844212) to a question like yours. Those two options offered are perfectly explained.

Comment: Status is a keyword in mysql not a reserved word so doesn't need backticks ,also every node needs to be backticked  if you do use backticks

Comment: If you use them, both parts need to be back ticked`\`b\`.\`Status\`` as Status

Comment: You don't need to escape a reserved word if it's after a `.`. So you can just write `b.Status`. Except that `b` should be either `rr` or `s`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly P.Salmon - Thank you!  your two answers combined answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this is covered in the MySQL manual here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

> If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, quote them individually rather than quoting the name as a whole. For example, write `my-table`.`my-column`, not `my-table.my-column`.